# Java Collection - Concrete data structure under the hood for dictionary/tree based abstract data structure

Tags: java, collections, abstract-data-type

My question is about what are the fundamental/concrete data structure (like array) used in implementing abstract data structure implementations like variations maps/trees?

I'm looking for what's used really in java collection, not theoretical answers.

Comment: You _could_, you know, just look at their source code.

Comment: `HashMap` source code from OpenJDK: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on quick code review of Sun/Oracle JDK. You can easily find the details yourself.

---

## Lists/queues

### `ArrayList`

Growing `Object[] elementData` field. Can hold 10 elements by default, grows by around 50% when cannot hold more objects, copying the old array to a bigger new one. Does not shrink when removing items.

### `LinkedList`

Reference to `Entry` which in turns hold reference to actual element, previous and next element (if any).

### `ArrayDeque`

Similar to `ArrayList` but also holding two pointers to internal `E[] elements` array - `head` and `tail`. Both adding and removing elements on either side is just a matter of moving these *pointers*. The array grows by 200% when is too small.

---

## Maps

### `HashMap`

Growing `Entry[] table` field holding so called *buckets*. Each bucket contains linked list of entries having the same hash of the key module table size.

### `TreeMap`

`Entry<K,V> root` reference holding the root of the red-black balanced tree.

### `ConcurrentHashMap`

Similar to `HashMap` but access to each bucket (called *segment*) is synchronized by an independent lock.

---

## Sets

### `TreeSet`

Uses `TreeMap` underneath (!)

### `HashSet`

Uses `HashMap` underneath (!)

### `BitSet`

Uses `long[] words` field to be as memory efficient as possible. Up to 64 bits can be stored in one element.

Comment: as i expected array is the pre-dominant concrete data structure for most of abstract data structures. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is of course one answer for each implementation. Look at the javadocs, they often describe these things. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/